# Как сделать чтобы переменная сохранялась при выходе из программы в python

Tags: python

Мне нужно сделать программу где есть переменная userName, но когда я выхожу из программы мне нужно чтобы эта переменная где то сохранилась и при следующем запуске кода переменная userName, так сказать, была востановленна.

**Главный вопрос как это сделать?**

Comment: Можно использовать конфиг файлы .ini, json или базу данных. 
Для первого используется библиотека [configparser](https://pypi.org/project/configparser/)

Comment: Можно еще сохранять в переменные окружения, разнообразности ради)) 
Но при выключении компьютера конечно же, не сохранится ничего, если не добавить в какой-нибудь .bashrc или любой другой конфиг shell'a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ссылка на ответ на английском СО](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66271284/saving-and-reloading-variables-in-python-preserving-names)

```
import pickle as pkl

with open('my_variables','wb') as f:
    pkl.dump([wb1,wbr,body_ang],f)

import pickle as pkl

with open('my_variables','rb') as f:
    new_script=pkl.load(f)
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрий человек